# can I charge a 3.6v device with a 5v charger?

Tags: voltage

I have a 3.6v screwdriver and cannot find the 3.6v charger for it. Can I use a 5v charger, or will it damage the device?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Electronics Stack Exchange. Please bear in mind that questions on use of electronic products are deemed off topic here.

Comment: Also, the answer is probably no, and might explode your battery.

Comment: It should be stated in the manual of the screwdriver that you should **only** charge it with the supplied charger. Use a different charger and you will risk the screwdriver being damaged or even catch fire.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to say without further details.

A "3.6V screwdriver" means a screwdriver with a nominal battery voltage* of 3.6V which practically means a single cell lithium ion/lithium polymer battery. Lithium ion batteries must be charged with a suitable charge control circuit.

The question then becomes where is that charge control circuit. It may well be that the charge control circuit is built into the tool and that the "charger" is simply a power brick. In this case 5V would be a perfectly reasonable input voltage for the tools built-in charge control circuit to charge a single lithium ion cell. It may well be that the reason you can't find your "3.6V" charger is because there never was one.

On the other hand it may well be that the charge control circuit is in the charger and using a straight power brick to charge the battery would be extremely risky.

* Note: the actual voltage of a battery varies considerablly with charge state, a single cell lithium ion/polymer battery usually has a nominal voltage of 3.6V or 3.7V but the fully discharged voltage will be somewhere around 2.8V to 3.0V and the fully charged voltage will be somewhere around 4.2V to 4.35V

Answer (score 1):

A 5v charger for a 3.6v device is very likely, maybe even guaranteed to damage your device in a serious way. You should use the charger that came with it or find an identical one. Remember that along with the output voltage rating there is also maximum output amperage, so not every 3.6v charger will work.

This answer could easily be questioned with google. Similarly, it isn't the place for such a question. Keep this in mind next time you ask!

Comment: The primary issue is the distinction between a "charger" and a "power supply" *for* a "charing circuit".  Your typical "USB phone charger" is a complete misnomer - it is actually a USB-style power supply for a charging circuit *inside* the phone.